# why is my kurtosis a negative number?

Tags: c++, boost, kurtosis

I am trying to calculate the kurtosis of a vector of numbers, the expected value is 1.5, however i get -1.5. Is there something i am missing from this code? Thanks in advance

```
using namespace boost::accumulators;
accumulator_set<float, stats<tag::mean, tag::kurtosis > > acc;
std::vector<float> v1 ;
v1.push_back(2);
v1.push_back(3);
v1.push_back(4);
acc = std::for_each( v1.begin(), v1.end(), acc ) ;
std::cout << kurtosis(acc) << std::endl ;
```

Comment: Whose `kurtosis` function are you using?  There is no such name in the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: it is using boost, i have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html#accumulators.user_s_guide.the_statistical_accumulators_library.kurtosis)

> The term -3 is added in order to ensure that the normal distribution has zero kurtosis.

Your result is negative because your data has less kurtosis than Gaussian distributed data.

Comment: ok i have taken a look at the documentation, how do i fix the problem?

Comment: @godzilla: What problem?  If you want absolute kurtosis, instead of relative to Gaussian, just add 3 again.

Comment: but is that a hack or will it work for all scenarios?

Comment: ben, if i leave it as minus 3 does this mean anything above 0 is a lepokurtuc and anything below zero is a platykurtic?

Comment: @godzilla: Yes, exactly.  The Boost function is calculating excess kurtosis, where zero is the threshold between platykurtic and lepokurtuc.  The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) describes excess kurtosis and why it is sometimes preferred to absolute kurtosis.